# How to integrate python chatbot to a website

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I have created a chatbot in python. I have also created a UI in html, css and js and connected the python chatbot to ui using flask. This is how it looks.

[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhCNJ.png)

How to flow goes is when a user inputs in the chat ui, the content is sent to flask and from flask to python file. The python file provides a response to flask app which passes the response to ui file where it is shown.

Now, the question is I have a different website and I want to integrate the UI created to this website. How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to extract your chatbot project into an independent project/package that may be installed/imported/integrated into your original project and any other projects.

Comment: You need to create an API out of the chat bot.

Comment: @Vishnudev I can create something like API. But, how would I create a front-end to display the responses.

Comment: Can you not use the UI you have built?

Comment: I have created UI saperately as shown in image. My question is how can I integrate that UI to a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you have the front-end and back-end separately, then what you have to do, is make `request` to your back-end that runs on a separate server and the front-end on other. Since you are using flask, this might be the sample of `route`:

```py
@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
    message = request.args["message"]
    reply = "Something to reply"
    return reply
```

Then, in the front-end you can make requests with JQuery

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourdomain.com/chat"
  data: {
    message: "The message from the client side"
  },
  success: (data)=> {
    //  do something with the reply here
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already found an alternative solution.

Comment: @KavanPatel could you share your solution? It doesn't add any value if you ask a question on StackOverflow and find an answer to it, but keep the answer to yourself.